# How do I UPDATE a field while moving it's value into another field?

Tags: mysql, sql

Imagine I have a table:

```
table1
    field1
    field2
```

I would like to store a value in field 1, and move its current value into field 2 in the same query.

Could I do something like this?

```
UPDATE table1 SET field2 = field1, field1 = ?
```

Comment: Have you tried your UPDATE?

Comment: Your `update` should work.  The values on the right-side of the update come from the "original" record.  The values on the left-side are set in the "new" record.

Comment: This is an odd requirement, and can be symptomatic of poor (i.e denormalised) design. Also note that when performing updates on multiple columns, the order in which things are done is important, so `SET field3 = field2,field2 = 'Z'` is not the same as `SET field2 = 'Z',field3 = field2`

Comment: @jarlh No, because I want to be sure before using it on my live server with important data.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Thank you. Could you please confirm that I should use this query or not on my live server? The answers are downvoted for some reason. I need to be confident about this decision. There is important data on the server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you have already given answer to your question. You can achieve what you want by this query:

```
UPDATE table1 SET field2 = field1, field1 = SourceofField
```

SourceofField is the variable or the source from where the value is coming.

Comment: Why is this answer downvoted? Should I not be using this?

Answer (score 0):

```
Update Table1 as T1 
LEFT JOIN Table1 as T2 ON T2.id = T1.id
SET T1.field2 = T2.field1, T1.field1 = 'X';
```

EDIT to explain it : 
[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/0406e/3)

**MySQL 5.6 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE table1
    (id MEDIUMINT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    field1 CHAR(30),
    field2 CHAR(30),
    PRIMARY KEY (id));

INSERT INTO table1
    (`field1`, `field2`)
VALUES
    ('','A'),
    ('foo','B'),
    ('bar','C');
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT  * FROM table1
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/0406e/3/0)**:

```
| id | field1 | field2 |
|----|--------|--------|
|  1 |        |      A |
|  2 |    foo |      B |
|  3 |    bar |      C |
```

Now I launch my Update request, here is the result :

```
    | id | field1 | field2 |
    |----|--------|--------|
    |  1 |      X |        |
    |  2 |      X |    foo |
    |  3 |      X |    bar |
```

Comment: Can you give a bit of context to your answer?

Comment: What do you mean by  context ? Do you mean that I need to explain my answer ?

Comment: Yes, because it seems like Z0q does not know much about SQL, so a little bit of explanation can be useful.